# Anyone gotten CryptoJS to work with Cybersource REST API v3 reporting for the Signature?

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, cybersource

Unable to generate correct HMAC 256 hash for Cybersource Signature headers

I have been working on this for a couple of days, and I can easily get it to work within .Net using the supplied sample code to generate the correct HMAC Signature.  However I cannot get CryptoJS to work, I beleive it stems from the fact that CryptoJS is interpreting the "\n" as a LRCF internally and thus throws the encryption off.  Please be aware that I am limited to ECMA5 and have brought the CryptoJS in as a minified function.

```
var data = "host: api.cybersource.com\ndate: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 20:41:05 GMT\n(request-target): get /reporting/v3/report-downloads?organizationId={OrgId}&reportDate=2019-06-06&reportName=PaymentBatchDetailReport\nv-c-merchant-id: {MerchId}";

var hash   = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data, "{SecretKey}");
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
document.write(base64);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey Chris, if this is JavaScript meant to run in the browser it is a really bad idea to send your secret key out for everybody to see. This along with our merchant ID will allow anybody to run any transaction they want including crediting credit cards (sending themselves money)!

Comment: No this is not where it will be used, we have an integration appliance that allows you to create custom Javascript functions for custom logic.  It will not leave the appliance. Thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to Base64 decode your secret key before passing it to CryptoJS.HmacSHA256.

For example 

`var words = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse({SecretKey});
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data, words);`

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was what I was missing, great job.